# Python Pandas: dataframe.loc returns "KeyError: label not in [index]", but dataframe.index shows it is

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm using the pandas toolkit in Python, and I'm have an issue.

I have a list of values, `lst`, and to make it easy let's say it has only the first 20 natural numbers:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

I then create a `DataFrame`, by giving it a `Series` with that list, like this:

```
>>> df = DataFrame(Series(lst))
```

And I want to use this to calculate the quantiles from **0.1** (10%) to **1** (100%), and I do it using the `quantile` function from DataFrame:

```
>>> quantiles = df.quantile(np.linspace(.1,1,num=10,endpoint=True))
```

If I print `quantiles`, this is what appears:

```
        0
0.1   2.9
0.2   4.8
0.3   6.7
0.4   8.6
0.5  10.5
0.6  12.4
0.7  14.3
0.8  16.2
0.9  18.1
1.0  20.0
```

Now, I want to store in a variable the value for quantiles **0.3** and **0.7**, and after searching for how to do it I came up with a solution using `loc` in the `DataFrame`, giving it the quantile label (`0.7`, for instance) and the column index of the series of values I want to consider. Since there's only one, I do it like this:

```
>>> q_3 = qts.loc[0.7][0]
```

The problem is that python gives me this error:

```
**KeyError: 'the label [0.7] is not in the [index]'**
```

But I know it exists, since if I try to print the `index` values, I get this:

```
>>> qts.index
Float64Index([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0], dtype='float64')
```

So, the index apparently exists, but I says it doesn't. 
What am I doing wrong?

If I try to print **any other** quantile value using this approach, rather than `0.3` or `0.7`, it works:

```
>>> qts.loc[0.1][0]
2.8999999999999999
>>> qts.loc[0.2][0]
4.8000000000000007
>>> qts.loc[0.4][0]
8.6000000000000014
>>> qts.loc[0.5][0]
10.5
>>> qts.loc[0.6][0]
12.4
>>> qts.loc[0.8][0]
16.200000000000003
>>> qts.loc[0.9][0]
18.100000000000001
>>> qts.loc[1][0]
20.0
```

Any thoughts?

I'm using Python 3.5, and pandas 0.20.3.

**EDIT**
Thanks for the feedback!
So, it's a float precision issue. Nevertheless, I was wondering: is there a better way to get the *N'th* element of the list of quantiles, rather than use `loc` as I did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index value is not *exactly* equal to 0.7 here; to a very small precision there is a difference. You can confirm this by running:

```
assert qts.index[6] == 0.7
```

or

```
print(qts.index[6] - 0.7)
```

If you round the index using `numpy.round` first you will be able to access the element via `qts.loc[0.7, 0]` as desired:

```
import numpy as np

qts.index = np.round(qts.index, decimals=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are a victim of float precision errors (some float values simply can't be represented in a finite binary form, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)).

While `qts.index` indeed outputs
 `Float64Index([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0], dtype='float64')`,

see what happens next:

```
>>>for i in qts.index: 
        print(repr(i))  

0.10000000000000001     
0.20000000000000001     
0.30000000000000004     
0.40000000000000002     
0.5                     
0.59999999999999998     
0.70000000000000007     
0.80000000000000004     
0.90000000000000002     
1.0
```

This still doesn't explain why `qts.loc[0.4][0]` works and `qts.loc[0.7][0]` doesn't work (one *possible* explanation might be that `.loc` does implement some kind of tolerance in case of float indexes ie if the error isn't too large it will "allow" accessing the required index), but `qts.loc[0.70000000000000007][0]` works:

```
>>> qts.loc[0.70000000000000007][0]
14.299999999999999
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others it's the precision issue. In order to locate desired floating number in the index you may want to use `np.isclose`

```
 >> quantiles.loc[np.isclose(quantiles.index, 0.3), 0]
 0.3    6.7              
 Name: 0, dtype: float64
 >> quantiles.loc[np.isclose(quantiles.index, 0.7), 0]
 0.7    14.3
 Name: 0, dtype: float64
```